# Require input in a hidden div to be filled; after goes back in display:block

Tags: javascript

I have a form on my page, with 3 questions(inputs). This is an example of 1 question on my from. Coded this input to show an additional DIV **ONLY** when a user puts a number greater than 0 in its field. The additional DIV is set to: **display:hidden** by default on the page until someone changes the question's input to greater than 0. What I need to do is that **REQUIRE** the text area in that DIV to be filled (IF DIV IS VISIBLE) before the page form can submit. I currently have this code:

```js
// Your listen for value changes in your input
  document.querySelector('#tix_quantity2').addEventListener('change', function calculate(e) {
  const div = document.querySelector('#div-to-show-hide');
  // Your grab the input value and test your condition
      if (Number(e.target.value) > 0)
      div.style.display = 'block';
    else
      div.style.display = 'none';
  });
```

```html
<input type="text"  class="NetscapeFix CalTicketQuantity form-control" name="tix_quantity" id="tix_quantity2" value="0" size="4" maxlength="4">

<div id="div-to-show-hide" class="additionaInfo" style="display:none;">INPUT: Text area (When visible on page. It needs to be required before the form on this page would submit)</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `textarea` visible on the required condition. If the element is visible then make the `textarea`s `required` value as `true`, or set it to `false`

```js
document.querySelector('#tix_quantity2').addEventListener('change', function calculate(e) {
    const div = document.querySelector('#div-to-show-hide');
    // Your grab the input value and test your condition
    if (Number(e.target.value) > 0) {
        div.style.display = 'block';
        const node = document.querySelector('#div-to-show-hide textarea');
        node.required = true;
    }
    else {
        div.style.display = 'none';
        const node = document.querySelector('#div-to-show-hide textarea');
        node.required = false;
    }
});
```

```html
<form action="">
    <input type="text" class="NetscapeFix CalTicketQuantity form-control" name="tix_quantity" id="tix_quantity2"
        value="0" size="4" maxlength="4">

    <div id="div-to-show-hide" class="additionaInfo" style="display:none;">
        <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The input field should be mentioned as a **required**.

```
<input type="text"  class="NetscapeFix CalTicketQuantity form-control" name="tix_quantity" id="tix_quantity2" value="0" size="4" maxlength="4" required>

<div id="div-to-show-hide" class="additionaInfo" style="display:none;">INPUT: Text area (When visible on page. It needs to be required before the form on this page would submit)</div>
```

Please check this.

Comment: Yes, but remember the div on page is on hidden mode by default, with with being hidden, it still check for that in the background and no one sees. How can I assign this "required" to only when the div is visible on page?

Comment: any ideas, please ??

Answer (score 0):

you can add "required" to textarea

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <textarea name="comment" required></textarea>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Yes, but remember the div on page is on hidden mode by default, with with being hidden, it still check for that in the background and no one sees. How can I assign this "required" to only when the div is visible on page?

Comment: any ideas, please ??

Comment: @MoeNagy Please check my solution.